# How to get Grandson　ActiveRecord Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :courses
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to: chapter
  has_many :modules
end

class Moudule < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to: course
end
```

I want to get Chapter's modules

I write a code.

```
module_list = []
chapter = Chapter.find(1)
chapter.courses.each |course| do
  course.modules.each |module| do
    module_list.push(module)
  end
end

module_list
```

but it is not smart.

- many each nest.
- module_list is not ActiveRecordObject.

Is there good way?

Answer (score 4):

This is what "through" associations are for:

```
class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :courses
  has_many :modules, :through => :courses
end

chapter = Chapter.find(1)
chapter.modules
```